# Can I use a shorter length anode rod?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have a 6 year old 80 gallon American water heater, looking to check/replace the anode rod for the first time. It currently has a 3/4" aluminum anode rod, 52" length. I need a flexible anode rod, as I have very little clearance to put a new one in.  The longest flexible one I found is 44".  Can I use a shorter anode rod than what it calls for?  Would it simply mean it may corrode faster?

Comment: how tall is the water heater tank?

Comment: You'll want to hold onto that beauty.  You can't buy another. 80 gallon resistive tank heaters are outlawed now.

Comment: Does your heater have a dedicated hex-head for the anode rod, or is the anode-rod attached to the fitting in the hot-water-outlet port? (a so-called "combo anode")

Comment: The heater is ~60" tall. It is a dedicated hex-head. Both HD and some other online site said the standard 3/4" flex 42" length would fit the heater, I just didn't know if there was an issue with putting a shorter rod in. This is the part:  https://www.supplyhouse.com/AO-Smith-100110266-3-4-NPT-Aluminum-Anode-Rod-52-Length.  In all fairness, I think I could get a 52" rod in there, but with the way it is facing, I would have to disassemble the connections because of the way everything is situated.  But if a flex 42" would work, then no disassembly would be needed.

Comment: If it currently has a 52” rod there should be no issue in getting another one of the same length in there - unless you have changed something else.

Comment: if there is a roof close above the tank access to fit a rigid anode will be tricky, this is why flexible anodes exist.

Comment: Correct, it sits in a closet that has 7' ceiling, plus the heater itself is about six inches off the ground.

Comment: Can you get a short combo rod perchance?  I'd feel more comfortable with a short combo + a short hexhead than with a shortened hexhead alone....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work still. Just make sure not to overtighten when replacing if it is a glass lined tank.